# Parsing Path Data in a SVG file in C

Tags: c, parsing, svg

I'm trying to parse the [data inside a path tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) to use it with a different program. I need to be able to interpret the different actions with the associated parameter values, something like building a structure which is a list of commands with the associated parameters would be great.

```
typedef struct _instruction{
    char type;

    float parameters[];
} Instruction;
```

So far I managed to extrapolate the `d` attribute value from the `<path>` inside the SVG file using [`libxml2`](http://xmlsoft.org/).

However the real challenge now is to get the actual instruction (e.g. `M100,200 C100,100.423 250,100.45 -250.2,200.33`) to an usable form. With usable form I mean getting strings like the one in the previous example to a structured form where I can iterate the different records containing the type of the instruction and the different parameters as float numbers (not strings).

I would love some insight on how to approach this problem, and, if possible, some code to get started, as I wasn't able to find any libraries written in c that would to this for me.

TL;DR

```
<path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
```

Comment: What is a _usable form_ ? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sure, an edit has been made trying to be more specific.

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895148/parsing-svg-path-in-objective-c) helps.

Comment: I wrote a parser in C++ that's part of Firefox: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/nsSVGPathDataParser.cpp you can use it under the terms of the MPL